# Using swear language - affects Google results and SEO in general negatively?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-adsense, content

I thought this is the right section - my main concern is search results, visibility, etc., not necessarily peoples' perception, as it's a blog-type of a site.

I saw recently a very popular site allow f**k in their title, which got me wondering: does it not affect or flag your site in some ways that you may not want it flagged? I want to occasionally use such words on my site, and the only reason I haven't yet is because I always thought that it may get flagged by Google or possibly other sites, or that I have to have a useless entry page where you have to enter your birthday (it's useless, truly), or something like that.

If it matters - I'd also like to use AdSense.

I just never investigated it, I just didn't do it due to irrational fear. Now I want to investigate it further and know the actual answer.

Comment: Adsense tolerates some level of swear words, however, does not generally like it because their advertiser pool wants to avoid controversy over having their ads appear on inappropriate pages. Otherwise, so far, there is not an issue I see. With all of the updates of late, the jury is still out. I rather suspect that Google is beginning to avoid some content, though I have no evidence of this just yet. Do keep in mind that the adult filter does use a different query mechanism against the Google index which can change a sites performance and not just because of the swear words.

Comment: What happens if AdSense dislikes my site due to occasional swear word? And I'm not going to write some "gangsta" site, I don't abuse the swear words, nor do I use many of them in general. So if you meant that my site may get flagged for content, that's not possible, unless it would be solely swear words that's being flagged. The topics aren't very 'adult' either, especially considering where today's newssites are going. The adult filter is probably the main thing I'm worried about, alongside my site being kicked way down the search results due to some sort of filtering process.

Comment: You should be okay. Some is to be expected from time to time. They just do not want adult content really. Google will just ask you to remove an ad from a specific page if they do not like it. You will have time to remove it. I got a no no letter once for a domain name.

Comment: I had better explain- I got a no no letter for a cr@p l0@d of bad domain names assigned to an IP address. Apparently I went over the line with several hundred of them. ;-0 Ooohh nooo....

Comment: Well, so far sounds like I've absolutely nothing to worry about as long as I don't load my pages with many swear words. That's great, as now I can stop feeling stupid after some word I would literally never use otherwise. Chuckled at your domain story, haha.

Comment: I understand the hesitation... I have rather used other words as a point but held off making for a colorful dance around what I really wanted to say. I have blog (not online yet) full of the more colorful language... not a lot... but this time I did not hold back. Afterall the topic, my life, is rather colorful anyway. I have an interesting past- a good one- but interesting to say the least. It was a bit wild.

Comment: Yea, I know what you mean. I was considering that as well, but held off from the idea - writing a personal blog. Now that I think of it - if at the time I would've started it instead - I would be so annoyed at having to sugarcoat and euphemize everything, so good thing I didn't do it. At least now, in this project, I will try to express myself the way I want to, without restraining self much in most situations.

Comment: Go for it! My blog is just for me and it is meant to remember. I will put it up sometime when there is more. It is unpolished and all over the place. Some nice stories and some rather- oh my God did he really do that? Just enjoy. I learned over the years that there is no sense in holding back too much. In he end, it does not really make a difference what people really know about me. It would not have stopped me from my work or my friends or my family.

Comment: Appreciate the advice! I really loathe holding back in any scenario and in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Jamie Wilkinson extracted a complete list of bad words banned by Google by examining the source code for the new service What Do You Love?. Entering any of these words into that website will display the search results for “kittens”.

Here’s the:
https://gist.github.com/jamiew/1112488

Comment: What does it mean for a word to be "banned by google?" There are some words that go both ways or are even in video game, book and movie titles or quotes. "My kid played with tennis balls" - that would be... Unsettling. Anyway. Question is now, what does it mean for them to be "banned", how does it affect me as a website owner and a writer who's focusing on SEO?